# Resize a svg to page width

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to strech a svg animation to fit the whole screen of the device.I want to display two instanes of the following svg animation such that each fills half of the screen width.And is there way to reposition the viewbox of the svg ?

jsFiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/8omxq2qp/

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 3387 1270">
<path id="planePath" class="planePath" d="M-226 626c439,4 636,-213 934,-225 755,-31 602,769 1334,658 562,-86 668,-698 266,-908 -401,-210 -893,189 -632,630 260,441 747,121 1051,91 360,-36 889,179 889,179" />
<g id="plane" transform="translate(-248,-306)">
<path id="note" fill="F23B3B" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z" />
 </g>
 <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
 <animateMotion xlink:href="#plane" dur="25s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
 <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
 </animateMotion >
 </svg>
```

css

```
html {background-color: #28505D;}

#plane {position: absolute;top: 20%;}

.planePath {stroke: #D9DADA;stroke-width: .1%;stroke-width: .5%;stroke-dasharray: 1% 2%;stroke-linecap: round;fill: none;}

.fil1 {fill: #D9DADA;}

.fil2 {fill: #C5C6C6;}

.fil4 {fill: #9D9E9E;}

.fil3 {fill: #AEAFB0;}
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle and above code do not match...but do you mean like this - https://jsfiddle.net/8omxq2qp/9/

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes,Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just remove any internal width declarations in the SVG and use

```
svg {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #28505D;
}
svg {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.planePath {
  stroke: #D9DADA;
  stroke-width: .1%;
  stroke-width: .5%;
  stroke-dasharray: 1% 2%;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}
.fil1 {
  fill: #D9DADA;
}
.fil2 {
  fill: #C5C6C6;
}
.fil4 {
  fill: #9D9E9E;
}
.fil3 {
  fill: #AEAFB0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 3387 1270">
  <path id="planePath" class="planePath" d="M-226 626c439,4 636,-213 934,-225 755,-31 602,769 1334,658 562,-86 668,-698 266,-908 -401,-210 -893,189 -632,630 260,441 747,121 1051,91 360,-36 889,179 889,179" />
  <g id="plane" transform="translate(-248,-306)">
    <path id="note" fill="F23B3B" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z" />
  </g>
  <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
  <animateMotion xlink:href="#plane" dur="25s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
    <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 3387 1270">
  <path id="planePath" class="planePath" d="M-226 626c439,4 636,-213 934,-225 755,-31 602,769 1334,658 562,-86 668,-698 266,-908 -401,-210 -893,189 -632,630 260,441 747,121 1051,91 360,-36 889,179 889,179" />
  <g id="plane2" transform="translate(-248,-306)">
    <path id="note" fill="F23B3B" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z" />
  </g>
  <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
  <animateMotion xlink:href="#plane2" dur="25s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
    <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8omxq2qp/10/)

One thing to note here (*inadvereant pun*)...I had to change the ID of the second "note" otherwise it doesn't appear in the second SVG.

That said, if you are using the SVG more than once, I'd suggest creating a `def` and the using a couple of `use` elements.

Comment: Thank You. I know this is a new topic not related to the question, but when when i try to scale the svg on hovering it gets displaced to a new position, is it possible to scale the svg and also make it follow the path?

Comment: You'd probably need to ask new question but my guess is that your `scale` transform is re-setting the transform you defined in the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this may help answer your question:

Note that I wrapped the SVG code inside of a div with the class of "responsive" in the HTML file. When using the same SVG multiple times you only need to change the id name of the graphics that you may wish to make changes to... e.g. note the changes in the duration for #plane2 and #plane3 that I added. Then removed the .svg and #plane definitions and added the .half-responsive and .full-responsive definitions that causes the svg to responsive to various screen sizes in the CSS file.

```css
html {
    background-color: #28505D;
}

.planePath {
    stroke: #D9DADA;
    stroke-width: .1%;
    stroke-width: .5%;
    stroke-dasharray: 1% 2%;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    fill: none;
}

.fil1 {
    fill: #D9DADA;
}

.fil2 {
    fill: #C5C6C6;
}

.fil4 {
    fill: #9D9E9E;
}

.fil3 {
    fill: #AEAFB0;
}

.half-responsive {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.full-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="author" content="Franciscus Agnew">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Responsive SVG Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="half-responsive">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 3387 1270">
      <path id="planePath" class="planePath" d="M-226 626c439,4 636,-213 934,-225 755,-31 602,769 1334,658 562,-86 668,-698 266,-908 -401,-210 -893,189 -632,630 260,441 747,121 1051,91 360,-36 889,179 889,179" />
      <g id="plane" transform="translate(-248,-306)">
        <path id="note" fill="F23B3B" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z" />
      </g>

      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion xlink:href="#plane" dur="25s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
        <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
      </animateMotion>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <div class="half-responsive">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 3387 1270">
      <path id="planePath" class="planePath" d="M-226 626c439,4 636,-213 934,-225 755,-31 602,769 1334,658 562,-86 668,-698 266,-908 -401,-210 -893,189 -632,630 260,441 747,121 1051,91 360,-36 889,179 889,179" />
      <g id="plane2" transform="translate(-248,-306)">
        <path id="note" fill="F23B3B" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z" />
      </g>

      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion xlink:href="#plane2" dur="50s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
        <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
      </animateMotion>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="full-responsive">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 3387 1270">
      <path id="planePath" class="planePath" d="M-226 626c439,4 636,-213 934,-225 755,-31 602,769 1334,658 562,-86 668,-698 266,-908 -401,-210 -893,189 -632,630 260,441 747,121 1051,91 360,-36 889,179 889,179" />
      <g id="plane3" transform="translate(-248,-306)">
        <path id="note" fill="F23B3B" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z" />
      </g>

      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion xlink:href="#plane3" dur="80s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
        <mpath xlink:href="#planePath" />
      </animateMotion>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, [Adobe Animate CC](https://www.adobe.com/products/edge-animate.html) would be a tremendous help with the work involved with animating SVG content for multiple screen sizes.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Paulie_D, Thanks for the input. It was my every intention to provide a more detailed answer to Renzous' question. I had to run and test my suggested answer before posting it in it's entirety. I will remember your advice in any of my future responses down the road... thanks!